# JavaFX 8 : ListView with Images and Label that autoscales/autoresizes

Tags: java, image, listview, javafx, javafx-8

I want to have an horizontal ListView which each ListCell contains an Image with a Label under it.

Apart from that the ListView will be on a GridPane so it's size can change.Knowing that I want each cell and it's content, in this case the image, to fill all the height.If the ListView changes size, the image and label should resize to fit on the new ListView size.

Right now it shows like this, if the image is smaller than the listView:

[smallerImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncBQS.png)

And if the image is bigger than the ListView it looks like this:
[biggerImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xe4a.png)

The problem with this is that it doesn't resize the image to fit the available Height.

Here is the code from the screenshots examples. It uses images from placeholdit:

```
package com.example;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                                                 launch(args);
                                                              }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Image> imagesObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(new ArrayList<>());
        for (int i = 0; i<10;i++) {
            // Adding 10 images
            //Bigger one
//            Image image = new Image("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=14&txt=150%C3%97300&w=150&h=300");
            //Smaller one
            Image image = new Image("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=14&txt=50%C3%97150&w=50&h=150");
//            Image image = new Image(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image_50x150.png").toString());
            imagesObservableList.add(image);
        }
        ListView<Image> listView = new ListView<>(imagesObservableList);
        listView.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        listView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Image>, ListCell<Image>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Image> call(ListView<Image> imageViewListView) {
                return new ListCell<Image>() {
                    ImageView imageView;
                    Label title;
                    VBox vBox;
                    {
                        vBox = new VBox();
                        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                        imageView = new ImageView();
                        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        title = new Label("Title");
                        title.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
                        vBox.getChildren().addAll(imageView,title);
                        vBox.setFillWidth(false);
                        setGraphic(vBox);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Image image, boolean bln) {
                        super.updateItem(image, bln);
                        imageView.setImage(image);
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.addRow(0);
        pane.addRow(1, listView);
        pane.addRow(2);
        pane.addColumn(0);
        RowConstraints topBottomConstraint = new RowConstraints();
        topBottomConstraint.setPercentHeight(30);
        RowConstraints centerConstraint = new RowConstraints();
        centerConstraint.setPercentHeight(30);
        pane.getRowConstraints().add(topBottomConstraint);
        pane.getRowConstraints().add(centerConstraint);
        pane.getRowConstraints().add(topBottomConstraint);
        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(100);
        pane.getColumnConstraints().add(columnConstraints);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

I guess the idea would be to bind the imageView.fitHeightProperty() to something. But I'm clueless what to bind. I tried binding it to the cell height and substract the "title" height like this:

```
ImageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(heightProperty().subtract(title.heightProperty()));
```

But it doesn't work as I expected and it shows weird until I scroll.